# Add hyperlink using aggregateTemplate on group Header in NgGrid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Can someone give some directions on how to customize the aggregate header of Ng-Grid the default template shows the data with group item count, If trying to do something like this but it's not reflecting on the group header

```
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    aggregateTemplate: '<div><div ng-click="row.toggleExpand()" ng-style="rowStyle(row)" class="ngAggregate"> <span class="ngAggregateText">{{row.label CUSTOM_FILTERS}}</span> <div class="{{row.aggClass()}}"></div></div><div ng-bind="row.label">Add Account</div> </div>',
    data: 'myData'    ,
    columnDefs: [{
        field: 'Account',
        displayName: 'Account',
        cellTemplate: '<div  ng-click="addAccount()" >{{row.getProperty(col.field)}} Add Team</div> ',
        visible: false
      }, {
        field: 'Date',
        displayName: 'Date',
        visible: false
      }
      , {
        field: 'Location',
        displayName: 'Location',
        cellTemplate: '<div  ng-click="foo()" ng-bind="row.getProperty(col.field)"></div>',
        width: '100px'

      }

    ]

  };
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. How does your myData look. Please show more code or try to create a Plunker. Which version of ng-grid are you using?

Comment: nothing the aggregate template changes were not reflecting on ng-grid as i was doing the grouping dynamically it's working now. Thanks now i'm able to edit